# Contains and remove methods for instances user-defined classes in a list?

Tags: java

So I have this code:

```
List<MyDataType> test = map.get(id)
MyDataType test1 = new MyDataType("XXX", 1); 
System.out.println(test.contains(test1)); // returns false
System.out.println(test.get(0).equals(test1)); // returns true
System.out.println(test.remove(test1)); // returns false 
System.out.println(test); // still the original list
```

I have already overridden the `.equals` and `.hashCode()` methods in MyDataType, and it is consistent. Furthermore, `map` is of type `ListMultimap<Long, DestQuanTuple>` (forgot to mention this in my OP.) However, the call:
`map.remove(sourceContainerId, test1)` does not modify `test` either.

The `MyDataType` class:

```
public class MyDataType implements Comparable<MyDataType> {
    private String destination;
    private int quantity;

    // Constructor initializes destination and quantity

    // Getters exist to get destination and quantity

    public boolean equals (MyDataType other) {
        boolean destinationSame = false, quantitySame = false;
        destinationsame = this.getDestination().equals(other.getDestination());
        Integer thisQuantity = (Integer) this.getQuantity();
        Integer otherQuantity = (Integer) other.getQuantity();
        quantitySame = thisQuantity.equals(otherQuantity);
        return destinationSame && quantitySame;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return destination.hashCode() + quantity;
    }

    public int compareTo(MyDataType other) {
        Integer myQuantity = this.getQuantity();
        if (myQuantity.compareTo(other.getQuantity()) != 0) {
            return myQuantity.compareTo(otherTuple.getQuantity());
        }
        else {
            return this.getDestination().compareTo(otherTuple.getDestination());
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why I'm not getting the functionality I want?

Comment: What is the actual type of `test`, an ArrayList or something else?

Comment: What happened to `System.out.println(test);`?

Comment: Show us your `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` implementation.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the implementation of contains in `DestQuanTuple`

Comment: Updated original post again.

Comment: You are not overriding/implementing the methods add `@Override` on all methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have to define `equals` and `hashCode` consistent

> `boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> Returns `true` if this list contains the
>   specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this
>   list contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null :
>   o.equals(e))`.

The contract is   `a.equals(b), then a.hashCode() must be same as b.hashCode().`

Conclusion, you have to override `equals` and `hashCode`

**UPDATE**

```
 public boolean equals (MyDataType other) {

 }
```

Must be,

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals (Object other) {

 }
```

Note that if you use override annotation then if you have an error won't compile, so use annotations!

You are overloading equals this often is not necesary cause it's difficult to mantain and in your case ,unexpected behaviour became cause collections use default `equals(Object o)` that's why you have that.

Comment: A link is enough, no need to paste the full content of the javadoc ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding the `equals()` method, actually overloading it.

Change the signature -

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object other) {
```

Following is what's going on -

```
System.out.println(test.contains(test1)); // returns false
```

false because internally the method called is `equals(Object obj)`.

```
System.out.println(test.get(0).equals(test1)); // returns true
```

true because you are calling the method `equals(MyDataType other)`.

```
System.out.println(test.remove(test1)); // returns false
```

false because internally the method called is `equals(Object obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that test is supposed to contain a MyDataType with values XXX and 1?

If so, you probably need to override the equals() method for MyDataType in order for List.Contains() and List.Remove() to find the MyDataType in the list.  The default equals() method will only return true if the MyDataTypes both point to the same object in memory.

Comment: If you override .equals(), you _must_ override .hashCode() as well!

Comment: Updated OP; please refer to it again. Thanks!